# What does "The Revenant" mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, bombshell

In *Bombshell* (2019), after several women accused Roger for sexual harassment, Geraldo spoke to an author Neil Cavuto:

> Geraldo: Look, I've known him for 40 years, and he's about as flirty
>   as the grizzly from **The Revenant**.
>
> Neil Cavuto: Let me tell you something. I called these allegations
>   sick because they are sick.

Wha does "The Revenant" mean?

Comment: I've downvoted for no apparent research. What pops up when you put "The Revenant" in Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a reference to  a movie of that name [*The Revenant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Revenant_(2015_film)) which features an attack by a grizzly bear.

> While scouting game, Glass is attacked by a grizzly bear and left near death.